# read client local time but not from user machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to read user's(client machine) local time. But I don't want to read it from client machine time. As user can tweak the time in his/her PC.

Here is what I thought of doing.

1. Read client IP address.
2. Use any GEOIP API to get the timezone of that IP
3. use C# **TimeZoneInfo** class and **ConvertTImeFromUTC** method to get the current local time on that zone

To read IP address

```
public static string GetUserIP(System.Web.HttpContext context)
{
    string retIPAddress = string.Empty;
    string sIPAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sIPAddress))
        retIPAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    else
        retIPAddress = sIPAddress.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
    return retIPAddress;
}
```

read timezone from IP address API, such as [IPInfoDB](http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=%3Cyour_api_key%3E&ip=%3Cipaddress%3E&format=json)

```
private static DateTime CurrentLocalTime()
{

    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("what ever the time zone name returned by API"));
}
```

This approach doesn't sound very reliable as Timezone id may not match from APIs.
is there any better approach to have this implemented?

Platform: ASP.NET

Comment: I would expect the # of geocoding errors to be greater than the # of people who have changed the time on their own computer.

Comment: IP address is not a valid indicator of time zone. For instance, at work, in Arizona, I appear to be on the East Coast of the United States - two or three hours away. I once had a job in the USA where I appeared to be in England.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders "I once had a job in the USA where I appeared to be in England" That makes me wonder how bad a Geolocation service you were using since US and England are in different RIRs.

Comment: The company was based in England and my IP address was from a group allocated at the company headquarters. They used their own routers, if I remember correctly, instead of relying on the infrastructure of a USA-based ISP.

Comment: @David this application will be used by IT developers to log their work timings, I am not trying to avoid human error on wrong PC times, but intentional time changes on client PC, to log different times

Comment: Only humans care about "Local Time".  Record **EVERYTHING** in UTC, and at the last momemt, before you have to present something to a human, convert it to their local time

Comment: @Gus this sounds like the only better option among all. Back to classic way...

Comment: You could you use JavaScript to set a hidden field value to the current hour in the client browser. Assuming the client PC's local time is off no more than ±60 minutes from its true timezone, you could then calculate the relative timezone offset for the client browser from the returned hidden field value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way of getting time from client machine

1. Client Time may not be reliable because client can change the time
2. There is some thing wrong with your technique, if someone is behind a vpn the time you will get wont be the client's time zone

Comment: Well we all understand the problem. That is why I posted the question to find if there is any better way (more reliable approach) to get client timezone or directly the client time.